# Azure Fuction App RabbitMQTrigger AES Encrypted message not being decrypted correctly. Payload doesn't seem to be a Base64 String

Tags: c#, encryption, azure-functions, rabbitmq, aes

apologies but i'm quite new to decrypting aes messages and RabbitMQ.

I have a azure fuction app with the following RabbitMQ Trigger:

Code:

```
    [FunctionName("RabbitMQTriggerTest")]       
public async Task Run([RabbitMQTrigger("event-vendor-create", ConnectionStringSetting = "RabbitMQConnection")] string item
  ,[DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,ILogger log)
{           
    string decryptedText = AesDecryptHelper.DecryptAes(item, _options.RabbitMQAesKey);
    log.LogInformation($"Decrypted Text: {decryptedText}");
}
```

The rabbitMQ server and Queue are something external to us and we only have listen permission, i'm using the following format to connect to it:

RabbitMQConnection: amqps://user:pass@hostName/vhost"

the trigger within the fuction app is being triggered and giving me the following type of message which firstly doesn't seem to be base64 or encoded correctly on my end once i've recieved it:

```
�5H�����c�5
�5By��S�(��gq�� �9���>���&���f�H��7��%���n���)ח���c{������8��
```

I have a static helper class called AesDecryptHelper with the method I call in the trigger fuction named DecryptAes.

Code:

```
public static string DecryptAes(string encryptedText, string aesKey)
{
    string decryptedJson = null;

    // Convert the AES key to bytes
    byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(aesKey);

    // Convert the input Base64 encoded string to bytes
    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

    // Create an AES decryptor
    using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = keyBytes;
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        // Assume the IV (Initialization Vector) is prepended to the encrypted data
        int ivSize = aesAlg.BlockSize / 8;
        byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];
        Array.Copy(encryptedBytes, 0, iv, 0, ivSize);
        aesAlg.IV = iv;

        // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform
        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
        {
            // Create the streams used for decryption
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes, ivSize, encryptedBytes.Length - ivSize))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream and deserialize the JSON
                        decryptedJson = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return decryptedJson;
}
```

but once it get to the following line it errors out:

```
byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
```

```
 System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: RabbitMQTriggerTest. System.Private.CoreLib: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
```

I've tried converting it to UTF8 then to a base 64 sting which seems to work but :

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptedText);
encryptedText =  System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
```

But once i try to decode it within the StreamReader:

```
decryptedJson = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
```

I get the following:

```
 System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: RabbitMQTriggerTest. System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms: The input data is not a complete block.
```

Again i'm quite new to this and i'm not sure if i'm running into issues because the intial item recieved from the queue isn't formatted correctly or if i need to convert it to a certian encoding type becore trying to decrypt it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is using RabbitMQ trigger that listens for messages and then decrypts them using AES encryption.

- It retrieves the encrypted message from the RabbitMQ queue ,  decrypt the message using AES encryption and log them.
- I followed this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-rabbitmq-trigger?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for RabbitMQ trigger for Azure Functions.

```cs
public static class Function
{
    [FunctionName("RabbitMQTriggerTest")]
    public static void Run(
        [RabbitMQTrigger("azures", ConnectionStringSetting = "sampath")] string encryptedMessage,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# RabbitMQ trigger function processed message: {encryptedMessage}");

       

        // Decrypt the message
        string decryptedMessage = DecryptAes(encryptedMessage, encryptionKey);
        log.LogInformation($"Decrypted Text: {decryptedMessage}");
    }
```

```cs
 public static string DecryptAes(string encryptedText, string aesKey)
    {
        string decryptedJson = null;

        try
        {
            
            byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(aesKey);

      
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

            byte[] iv = new byte[16]; 
            Array.Copy(encryptedBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

          
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = keyBytes;
                aesAlg.IV = iv;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

             
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
                {
           
                    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encryptedBytes, iv.Length, encryptedBytes.Length - iv.Length))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                            {
                                // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream and deserialize the JSON
                                decryptedJson = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Output:**
[image]